# UBUNTU 16 LTS, node v8 Illegal Instruction core dump

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04, armv7

I am trying to install nodejs v8 in nanopc(armv7l) using 
`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`. 
The installation is fine. I used `which npm and which node` and it shows the correct path. 
But if I try `node -v, npm -v` I get

> Illegal instruction (core dumped) 
>   error.

Does anyone knows how to resolve this and why it works for version 10 and not for older version.